# tune up request headers to be accepted by spring boot resource

Tags: java, spring-boot, request, multipartform-data

my Spring Boot Resource is not receiving my requests.
this is the resource definition:

```
@PostMapping(name = "sign_one_doc", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> signDocument(
            @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile data,
            @RequestPart("isTimestamping") boolean isTimestamping,
            @RequestPart("isMakeCheck") boolean isMakeCheck,
            @RequestPart("signMode") int signMode,
            @RequestPart("certClientID") int certClientID,
            @RequestPart("isCertLocal") boolean isCertLocal
    ) throws IOException, DocSignException, InputStreamReadException {
        RequestData requestData
                = signCtrl.signFile(data.getInputStream(), data.getOriginalFilename(), signMode, certClientID, isTimestamping, isMakeCheck, isCertLocal);

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        InputStreamResource inputStreamResource = new InputStreamResource(requestData.currentCtxFile());
        headers.setContentLength(requestData.currentCtxFileBA().length);
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
        return new ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource>(inputStreamResource, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

request that I'm sending (via Insomnia) has `content-type: multipart/form-data` and `accept: application/octet-stream` set
[image]

but when I send this requeste spring just says:

```
 Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/octet-stream' not supported]
 Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation]
```

what am I setting wrong and why? also, would you be so kind and provide curl request for this resource?

I have tried:
`curl -v --include -F isTimestamping=false -F file=@test.pdf -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' http://localhost:8080/sign_one_doc`

but spring fails with:

`java.io.EOFException: Unexpected EOF read on the socket`

man, it's hard to sent a request, everything that's possible just fails :D

Answer (score 0):

I need to change `@RequestPart` to `@RequestParam`.
curl issue still unresolved